# PHP FTP upload to specific folder

Tags: php, ftp

I want to upload all files to a specific directory

This script works fine

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename)
{
    ftp_put($ftp_conn, basename($filename), $filename, FTP_BINARY);
}
```

How to edit it to make it work to a specific directory? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
// connect and login to FTP server
$usr = '*****';`enter code here`
$pwd = '******';
$ftp_server = "*******";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $usr, $pwd);    
$ftp_path = '/public_html/';    
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename)    
{
    ftp_put($ftp_conn, $ftp_path, $filename, FTP_BINARY);     
}
 
// check upload status:
print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
print "\n";

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second param in [`ftp_put()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) should include the path and the filename.

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    $ftp_path = $ftp_path = '/public_html/'.$filename;
    ftp_put($ftp_conn,$ftp_path , $filename, FTP_BINARY);
}
```